# Is a locally square integrable local martingale locally a square integrable martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, martingales, stochastic-analysis

In some posts (in the comments of the [answer to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688286/definition-of-semimartingale-in-protters-book), in the [answer to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902733/question-about-protters-proof-that-a-cadlag-locally-square-integrable-local-ma) and in the comments to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635406/locally-square-integrable-local-martingales)) people used the argument that

> a stochastic process $X$ which is a local martingale (i.e. there is a localizing sequence $T_n$ s.t. $X^{T_n}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale) and locally a square integrable process (i.e. there is another localizing sequence $S_n$ s.t. $\forall t\geq0: \mathbb E (X_t^{S_n})^2<\infty$) is locally a square integrable martingale (i.e. there is localizing sequence $R_n$ s.t. $X^{R_n}$ is a martingale and $\forall t\geq0: \mathbb E (X_t^{R_n})^2<\infty$).

But none of them could give an propper answer to the question how this can be proofed. I understand all of their proofs except of the part they always skipped: why the processes $X^{T_n\land S_n}$ or $X^{T_n\land S_n\land n}$ should be still square integrable. I think square integrability is not stable under stopping.

I think a lot of people are confused if this detail is not clearly distinguished, what might have caused for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911653/square-integrable-local-martingale-or-locally-square-integrable-martingale). This is the reason why I want to clear this question once and for all:

Can anyone either give a propper proof that a locally square integrable local martingale (i.e. there are localizing sequences $T_n, S_n$ s.t. $X^{T_n}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale and $\forall t\geq0: \mathbb E (X_t^{S_n})^2<\infty$) is locally a square integrable martingale (i.e. there is localizing sequence $R_n$ s.t. $X^{R_n}$ is a martingale and $\forall t\geq0: \mathbb E (X_t^{R_n})^2<\infty$), or give a counterexample which is a local martingale and a locally square integrable process, but not locally a square integrable martingale.

If you give a proof of the first I'm especially (and actually only) interested in the part why square integrability is stable under stopping.

Comment: Maybe lemma 5 here could do the trick https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/23/localization/

Comment: @TheBridge: Thank you, but unfortunately the paragraph between def. 3 and def. 4 in the link you mentioned confirms my suspicion that being square integrable is not stable under localization. This is the reason why in the link $X_t^*=\sup_{s\leq t} X_s$ is introduced, but this is not the case I'm considering in the question.

Comment: @TheBridge: But I think your comment is relevant anyway, because it seems to solve some of the questions I referred in my question above. Some books, like the one of Protter, had not been accurate enough when they have used the term 'locally square integrable'. It seems they meant I in the sense of the link (using $X^*$) and not simply to hold when being stopped by a suitable sequence of stopping times.

Comment: Stability in the sense of Lowther's post is all you need along lemma 5 to get your point. Take $P$ = square int, $Q$ = UI Martingale, then $(P\cap Q)_{loc} = P_{loc} \cap Q_{loc} $ if $P$ and $Q$ are stable. The class Q of UI Martingales is stable by optimal sampling unless mistaken so Q is ok. The question remains for P, i.e. "is a stopped $L^2$ process $L^2$ ?" But John Dawkins crashed the point with BDG inequalities (just removing subscript n and you get it). I don't know though if there is (or not) a more basic argument for the stability of P as BDG seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @TheBridge: Unfortunately, at the point you referred to John Dawkins answer, his answer turned out to be incorrect/insufficient. Do you have an idea to proof this point or give a counterexample?

Comment: Ok I'll take a look, but I didn't see where the problem was in is point. Too bad

Comment: By BDG we just get ($R_n:=T_n\land S_n$) $$\Bbb E\Big((X_t^{R_n})^2\Big)\leq \Bbb E\Big(\left[X^{S_n}\right]_t\Big),$$ where $\left[X^{S_n}\right]$ means the quadratic variation of the stopped process $X^{S_n}$. To go on form this we would like to use  $\Bbb E\Big(\left[X^{S_n}\right]_t\Big)= \Bbb E\Big((X^{S_n}_t)^2\Big)$. But to use this, we need to know $\Bbb E\Big(\left[X^{S_n}\right]_t\Big)<\infty$ for all $t\geq0$, what we don't know.